# Python list can't get into an element inside a list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a class that I built and when I print the list in which the len is 150. This is a list of lists like the following:

```
[{'id': '1344125', 'date': '2022-01-16', 'money': '158.0', 'vat': '7.6', 'payment': 'PayPal'}], [{'id': '1234125', 'date': '2022-01-12', 'money': '124.0', 'vat': '12.12', 'payment': 'CC'}]]
```

When I am trying to get into a value in one of the lists I get an error

```
print(lst[0][1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: That's a list of dictionaries, not a list of lists.

Comment: Your nested `lists` only have 1 value (index `0`), consisting of a `dict`. Hence the error.

Comment: You're missing a `[` at the beginning.

Comment: Why is each dictionary wrapped in a nested list? Can those lists have more than one dictionary in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your list looks like:

```
[                  # outer list

    [              # inner list 1
        {}         # single element inside inner list 1
    ],

    [              # inner list 2
        {}         # single element insider inner list 2
    ],
    ...
]
```

Since all inner lists consists of a single item, that item can only be accessed using 0th index. Using any other index would be illegal and throw index out of range exception.

Here's how this could be debugged:

```
print(len(outer_list))
for inner_list in outer_list:
    print(len(inner_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because yout list is out of range. You are accessing second place value which does not exist as len(lst) is `1` and you can to access this with `lst[0]`.

try using
`print(lst[0][0]['id'])`.
First namespace`[0]`gives you -
**[{'id': '1344125', 'date': '2022-01-16', 'money': '158.0', 'vat': '7.6', 'payment': 'PayPal'}]**

Second namespace `[0]` gives you
**{'id': '1344125', 'date': '2022-01-16', 'money': '158.0', 'vat': '7.6', 'payment': 'PayPal'}**

and last namespace `['id']` - **1344125**